# How can I merge separate UV maps?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

This model has a different mesh and UV map for its eyes, I wanna join the eye mesh with the rest of the head..

[image: b]
[image: e]

But when I just Ctrl-J, it joins together but the eye's UV map doesn't go with it. Is there a way I can copy the eye's UV map and add it to the head model?

[image: r]

Comment: This will merge the UV maps if they have the same name. You can rename the UVMaps in the object data propertis panel (click on the litle green triangle on the right side) and search for UV Maps. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv/layout_management.html

Comment: Duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92767/combining-2-uv-maps-into-one